# finding a remainder of an integer and a list element in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will create 10 random numbers and test if they are even or odd.
I have a list called rand_list created by

```
rand_list = []

for int in range(10):  
    rand_list.append(random.randint(1,1000))
    intermediary = rand_list.append(random.randint(1,1000))
    remainder2 = intermediary % 2 #this statement produces an error
    print("the \i number is even \n", rand_list[int])
    else:
        print("the \i number is odd \n", rand_list[int])
```

I do not understand why  if  remainder == 0: does not work.  it gives me {TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'}   Am i comparing two different types of objects?

Answer (score 3):

`remainder2 = intermediary %2` produces an error because `list.append()` returns None, as the error states.  You're also appending 2 random ints to the list every time.  What you probably want is `intermediary = rand_list[-1]` which will return the last element in the list.

In addition, please provide working/well-formatted code in your questions.  The indentation is a little confusing and you're missing a line of code as well.

Answer (score 1):

the `append()` function does not return anything. It modifies the list in place. What you would want to do is something like this

```
rand_list.append(random.randint(1,1000))
intermediary = rand_list[-1]
remander2= intermediary % 2
```

or perhaps cleaner:

```
intermediary = random.randint(1,1000)
rand_list.append(intermediary)
remainder2 = intermdiary % 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What about as your if statement, you use

```
if number%2 == 0
  # is even
else
  # is odd
```

You are receiving the TyperError because you are assigning a method call to a veritable - this does nothing at all (hence the NoneType in your error message). You then try and perform an operation on this NoneType as if it were an Int. This wont work.

Comment: this is not very helpful answer... and does not answer why OP is getting `TypeError`

Comment: I figured its an improved way of doing it that will avoid the TypeError. But let me do as you say then...

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code.

1) `list.append()` modyfies list in place, adding new element on the end.
It does not return anything, or to be more precise, it returns `None`.
So your `intermediary == None` and you cannot use `%` operator 
with `None`...

You can assign your random number to variable:

```
x = random.randint(1,1000)
rand_list.append(x) # append it to your list
remainder = x % 2 # take remainder using
```

Because you only care if it is zero or not, you can later use fact, 
that zero is equal to `False` in boolean context, and all other number 
are treated as `True`
So you can write instead:

```
is_odd = x % 2
```

or more readable:

```
is_odd = bool(x % 2)
```

2) The other problem is, that you missed `if` in your code. 
In fact, you didn't even use your `remainder2` variable!
The correct code would be:

```
if (remainder2 == 0):
    print("the \i number is even \n", rand_list[int])
else:
    print("the \i number is odd \n", rand_list[int])
```

or using my advice above:

```
if is_odd:
    print("the \i number is odd \n", x)
else:
    print("the \i number is even \n", x)
```

3) The last thing is, that as @Padraic Cunningham pointed out, 
you should not use `int` as variable name. It does not produce error, 
as you shadow name of type `int` and builtin `int()`.

To sum up, your code could look like this:

```
rand_list = []

for i in range(10):  
    x = random.randint(1,1000)
    if (x % 2):
        print(i, '-', x, "- the number is odd.")
    else:
        print(i, '-', x, "- the number is even.")
```